# Click anywhere on a div with text and still trigger event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with `className="box-container"` and it contains four div's which all have `className="box"`. The four contained div's have unique id's, text in them and an icon which define their purpose.

I have a "click" event listener which triggers a function depending on the box clicked by the user and I use `e.target.id` to get the id of the box selected.

The problem is that if the user presses on the text or the icon inside the box then  I do not get the id required to properly execute the function. They can only select  on the blank spaces in the box for proper execution of the functions and that's not ideal.

**I'd like for the user to select anywhere inside the box and  have the function execute using the box id.**

- I could change how I structured the information in the box div's but that will mean restyling (time consuming)
- or have if statements which check e.target.parentElement.id

but I feel there may be another more efficient way.

The correct output: After clicking on a box, a div is added and when an item in the drop downlist is selected "resource element details appear (circled in red)

expected output :

[image]

Problem output: After clicking on text or icon in box, the dropdown appears but selecting an item yields nothing.

Here is the code. The **javascript function worth looking at is called addClass(e),** I just added all the code because its all connected.

```js
var box_container = document.getElementById("box-container");
var quote_body = document.getElementById("quote-body");
box_container.addEventListener("click", showPanel);
quote_body.addEventListener("change", calculateCost);

var f_pos = 0; var a_pos = 0; var t_pos = 0; var s_pos = 0; var g_total = 0;

function showPanel(e) {
    if(e.target.id === "box-container") {}
    else {
        addClass(e);
        document.getElementById("quote-body").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById("gt-div").style.display = "inline";
    }
}

function createLi(e) {
    //this function creates the list element (li)

    var li_element = document.createElement("li");

    var r_num = document.createElement("input");
    r_num.setAttribute("type", "number");
    r_num.setAttribute("max", "20");
    r_num.setAttribute("min", "1");
    r_num.id = "resorce-amount";

    var r_label1 = document.createElement("label");
    r_label1.textContent =" " + e.target.value + " for ";
    r_label1.id = "chosen-lbl";

    var r_duration = document.createElement("input");
    r_duration.setAttribute("type", "number");
    r_duration.setAttribute("max", "30");
    r_duration.setAttribute("min", "1");
    r_duration.id = "resource-duration";

    var r_type = document.createElement("select");
    r_type.id = "time-type";
    r_type.appendChild(new Option("---select---", "none"));
    r_type.appendChild(new Option("hours", "hours"));
    r_type.appendChild(new Option("days", "days"));
    r_type.appendChild(new Option("weeks", "weeks"));
    r_type.appendChild(new Option("months", "months"));

    var r_label2 = document.createElement("label");
    r_label2.id = "country-lbl";
    r_label2.textContent = " from ";

    var r_country = document.createElement("select");
    r_country.id = "country-lbl";
    r_country.appendChild(new Option("-----select-----", "none"));
    r_country.appendChild(new Option("South Africa", "South Africa"));
    r_country.appendChild(new Option("Israel", "Israel"));
    r_country.appendChild(new Option("China", "China"));

    var r_remove = document.createElement("button");
    r_remove.className = "remove-btn";
    r_remove.textContent = "X";
    r_remove.addEventListener("click", removeResource);

    //console.log("creat li function: " + e.target.id);

    //invisible divs for cost estimates
    var num      = document.createElement("label"); num.id      = "r-num";      //num.style.visibility      = "hidden";
    var duration = document.createElement("label"); duration.id = "r-duration"; //duration.style.visibility = "hidden";
    var type     = document.createElement("label"); type.id     = "r-type";     //type.style.visibility     = "hidden";
    var rate     = document.createElement("label"); rate.id     = "r-rate";     //rate.style.visibility     = "hidden";
    var estimate = document.createElement("label"); estimate.id = "r-estimate"; //estimate.style.visibility = "hidden";

    var r_position = document.createElement("label"); r_position.id = "r-position"; r_position.style.visibility = "hidden";

    //e.target.id being the id of the box
    if(e.target.id === "field-dropdown")
    {   
        r_position.value = f_pos;
        r_remove.id = "remove-field";
        estimate.className = "field-estimate";
        estimate.id = "field-estimate";
        li_element.id = "field-element-" + f_pos;
        li_element.className = "li-element-field";
        f_pos++;
    }
    if(e.target.id === "admin-dropdown")
    { 
        r_position.value = a_pos;
        estimate.className = "admin-estimate";
        estimate.id = "admin-estimate";
        r_remove.id = "remove-admin";   
        li_element.id = "admin-element-" + a_pos;   
        li_element.className = "li-element-admin";
        a_pos++;
    }
    if(e.target.id === "tech-dropdown")
    { 
        r_position.value = t_pos;
        estimate.className = "tech-estimate";
        estimate.id = "tech-estimate";
        r_remove.id = "remove-tech";
        li_element.id = "tech-element-" + t_pos;
        li_element.className = "li-element-tech";
        t_pos++;
    }
    if(e.target.id === "student-dropdown")
    {
        r_position.value = s_pos;
        estimate.className = "student-estimate";
        estimate.id = "student-estimate";
        r_remove.id = "remove-student";
        li_element.id = "student-element-" + s_pos;
        li_element.className = "li-element-student";
        s_pos++;
    }

    li_element.appendChild(r_num);
    li_element.appendChild(r_label1);
    li_element.appendChild(r_duration);
    li_element.appendChild(r_type);
    li_element.appendChild(r_label2);
    li_element.appendChild(r_country);
    li_element.appendChild(r_remove);

    li_element.appendChild(num);
    li_element.appendChild(duration);
    li_element.appendChild(rate);
    li_element.appendChild(estimate);
    li_element.appendChild(r_position);

    li_element.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

    return li_element;
}

function addResource(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if( e.target.id === "field-dropdown") //where did the request come from (which element triggered the request)
    {
        document.getElementById("field-list").appendChild(createLi(e));
    }
    if( e.target.id === "admin-dropdown")
    {
        document.getElementById("admin-list").appendChild(createLi(e));
    }
    if( e.target.id === "tech-dropdown")
    {
        document.getElementById("tech-list").appendChild(createLi(e));
    }
    if( e.target.id === "student-dropdown")
    {
        document.getElementById("student-list").appendChild(createLi(e));
    }
}

function addClass(e) {
    if( document.getElementsByClassName("quote-container").length <= 4 ) {
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        var form      = document.createElement("form");
        var ul        = document.createElement("ul");

        var temp_dd = document.createElement("select");
        var lbl     = document.createElement("label");
        var div     = document.createElement("div");  
        var div_lbl = document.createElement("div");

        var dropdown;

        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "10% 90%";
        container.style.display =  "grid";
        
        //e.target.id being the id of the box the user clicked on
        if( e.target.id === "fieldBox" )   { 
            container.className = "admin-container";
            temp_dd.id = "field-dropdown";
            container.id = "f-body";
            ul.id = "field-list";
            lbl.id = "f-estimate";
        }
        if( e.target.id === "adminBox" )   { 
            container.className = "admin-container";
            temp_dd.id = "admin-dropdown";
            container.id = "a-body";
            ul.id = "admin-list";
            lbl.id = "a-estimate";
        }
        if( e.target.id === "techBox" )    { 
            container.className = "tech-container";
            temp_dd.id = "tech-dropdown";
            container.id = "t-body";
            ul.id = "tech-list";
            lbl.id = "t-estimate";
        }
        if( e.target.id === "studentBox" ) { 
            container.className = "student-container";
            temp_dd.id = "student-dropdown";
            container.id = "s-body";
            ul.id = "student-list";
            lbl.id = "s-estimate";
        }

        //will be set from php data, but for now this...
        temp_dd.appendChild(new Option("-----select-----", "none"));
        temp_dd.appendChild(new Option("Secratary", "Secratary"));
        temp_dd.appendChild(new Option("Data capturer", "Data capturer"));
        temp_dd.appendChild(new Option("Clerk", "Clerk"));

        dropdown = temp_dd;
        dropdown.addEventListener("change", addResource);

        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "10% 90%";
        container.className = "quote-container";
        container.style.display = "grid";

        form.id = "skill-form";

        //ul.appendChild(createLi(e));

        form.appendChild(dropdown);
        container.appendChild(form);
        container.appendChild(ul);
        container.appendChild(div_lbl);
        container.appendChild(lbl);
        container.appendChild(div);

        document.getElementById("quote-body").appendChild(container);
    }
    else{
        /*var g_total = document.createElement("label");
        g_total.id = "grand-total";
        g_total.innerText = "made";
        document.getElementById("quote-body").appendChild(g_total);
        console.log("over the limit");*/
    }
}

function removeResource(e) {
    if(e.target.classList.contains("remove-btn")) {
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            var r_remove = e.target.parentElement;
            //console.log("delete function id: " + e.target.id);
            if (e.target.id === "remove-field")   { document.getElementById("field-list").removeChild(r_remove); f_pos--;}
            if (e.target.id === "remove-admin")   { document.getElementById("admin-list").removeChild(r_remove); a_pos--;}
            if (e.target.id === "remove-tech")    { document.getElementById("tech-list").removeChild(r_remove); t_pos--;}
            if (e.target.id === "remove-student") { document.getElementById("student-list").removeChild(r_remove); s_pos--;}
        }
    }
    //calculateCost(e);
}

function calculateCost(e) {
    var f_arr; var a_arr; var t_arr; var s_arr;
    //e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value = "2";

    if(e.target.id === "resorce-amount")
    {
        document.getElementById("r-num").value = e.target.value;
    }
    if(e.target.id === "resource-duration")
    {
        document.getElementById("r-duration").value = e.target.value;
    }
    if(e.target.id === "time-type")
    {
        if(e.target.value === "hours")  { e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value = "2";}
        if(e.target.value === "days")   { e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value = "16";}
        if(e.target.value === "weeks")  { e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value = "80";}
        if(e.target.value === "months") { e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value = "320";}

        if(e.target.parentElement.className === "li-element-field")   {type = e.target.value;}
        if(e.target.parentElement.className === "li-element-admin")   {type_a = e.target.value}
        if(e.target.parentElement.className === "li-element-tech")    {type_t = e.target.value}
        if(e.target.parentElement.className === "li-element-student") {type_s = e.target.value}
    }

    if(e.target.parentElement.className === "li-element-field") {
        //geting calculation variables from the list element's children via eve
        var num = e.target.parentElement.children.item(0).value;
        var dur = e.target.parentElement.children.item(2).value;
        var rte = e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value;   
        var est = 0;
        if(!isNaN(num*dur*rte))
            est = num*dur*rte;

        e.target.parentElement.children.item(10).value = est;

        //gets all active field estimates as HTML collection
        f_arr = document.getElementsByClassName("field-estimate");

        //gets position of the element from id
        var pos = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.id.slice(14,15));
        var total = 0;

        for(var i = 0 ; i<f_arr.length;i++)
        {//stores calculated element estimates in a HTML collection based on element pos then sums the total estimates in the collection
            f_arr[pos].value = est;
            total += f_arr[i].value;
            g_total += total;
        }
        if(!isNaN(total))
            document.getElementById("f-estimate").innerText = "Field resource estimate: R " + total;
    }
    if(e.target.parentElement.className === "li-element-admin") {
        //geting calculation variables from the list element's children via event trigger
        var num = e.target.parentElement.children.item(0).value;
        var dur = e.target.parentElement.children.item(2).value;
        var rte = e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value;   
        var est = 0;
        if(!isNaN(num*dur*rte))
            est = num*dur*rte;

        e.target.parentElement.children.item(10).value = total;

        //gets all active field estimates as HTML collection
        a_arr = document.getElementsByClassName("admin-estimate");

        //gets position of the element from id
        var pos = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.id.slice(14,15));
        var total = 0;

        for(var i = 0 ; i<a_arr.length;i++)
        {//stores calculated element estimates in a HTML collection based on element pos
            a_arr[pos].value = est;
            total += a_arr[i].value;
            g_total += total;
        }
        if(!isNaN(total))
            document.getElementById("a-estimate").innerText = "Admin resource estimate: R " + total;
    }
    if(e.target.parentElement.className === "li-element-tech") {
        //geting calculation variables from the list element's children via event trigger
        var num = e.target.parentElement.children.item(0).value;
        var dur = e.target.parentElement.children.item(2).value;
        var rte = e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value;   
        var est = 0;
        if(!isNaN(num*dur*rte))
            est = num*dur*rte;

        e.target.parentElement.children.item(10).value = total;

        //gets all active field estimates as HTML collection
        t_arr = document.getElementsByClassName("tech-estimate");

        //gets position of the element from id
        var pos = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.id.slice(13,14));
        var total = 0;

        for(var i = 0 ; i<t_arr.length;i++)
        {//stores calculated element estimates in a HTML collection based on element pos
            t_arr[pos].value = est;
            total += t_arr[i].value;
            g_total += total;
        }
        if(!isNaN(total))
            document.getElementById("t-estimate").innerText = "Tech resource estimate: R " + total;
    }
    if(e.target.parentElement.className === "li-element-student") {
        //geting calculation variables from the list element's children via event trigger
        var num = e.target.parentElement.children.item(0).value;    
        var dur = e.target.parentElement.children.item(2).value;
        var rte = e.target.parentElement.children.item(9).value;   
        var est = 0;
        if(!isNaN(num*dur*rte))
            est = num*dur*rte;

        e.target.parentElement.children.item(10).value = total;

        //gets all specified estimates as HTML collection
        s_arr = document.getElementsByClassName("student-estimate");

        //gets position of the element from id
        var pos = parseInt(e.target.parentElement.id.slice(16,17));
        var total = 0;

        for(var i = 0 ; i<s_arr.length;i++)
        {//stores calculated element estimates in a HTML collection based on element pos
            s_arr[pos].value = est;
            total += s_arr[i].value;
            g_total += total;
        }
        if(!isNaN(total))
            document.getElementById("s-estimate").innerText = "Student resource estimate: R " + total;
    }
    document.getElementById("g-total").innerText = "Grand total: R " + g_total;
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    height:300px;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'title_ title_ title_ title_ title_'
        'bcontainer bcontainer bcontainer bcontainer bcontainer'
        'qcontainer_ qcontainer_ qcontainer_ qcontainer_ qcontainer_';
}
.heading-container {
    grid-area: title_;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}
.box-container {
    grid-area: bcontainer;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}
.quote-container {
    grid-area: qcontainer_;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightcyan;
}

/*setting size of a box to be contained*/
.box {
    width: 260px;
    height: 160px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    transition: 1s;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1.5px solid #bdbdbd;
}

.box:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content-box {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-left: 2px solid #d8d8d8;
    border-right: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-color: none;
}

.fa-user-cog, .fa-user-edit, .fa-user-tie,
.fa-user-graduate {
    color: #0e9aa7;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.sub-heading {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.sub-heading-2 {
    color: black;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 60px;
}

.skill-level {
    color: grey;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.skill-level-2 {
    color: grey;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.examples {
    font-size: x-small;
    color: grey;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}

/*Instruction Phrase*/
.choose-instruction {
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

body {/*of entire page*/
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

input {
    font-size: 13.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Hallabak-Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/cropped-Signage-Logo-32.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Navigation Menu stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container" id="grid-container">
        <!-- cntains pgae heading -->
        <div class="heading-container">
            <h1>Estimated team quote</h1>
            <h4>choose skill level</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- contains 4 box elements -->
        <div class="box-container" id="box-container">
            <!-- field box -->
            <div class="box" id="fieldBox">
                <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-cog fa-4x"></i></div>
                <div class="content-box">
                    <div class="sub-heading"><h6>Field team</h6></div>
                    <div class="skill-level">entry-level</div>
                    <div class="examples">Data collectors,</br>Sales person,</br>Waiters...etc</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- admin box -->
            <div class="box" id="adminBox">
                <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-edit fa-4x"></i></div>
                <div class="content-box">
                    <div class="sub-heading"><h6>Admin & Support</h6></div>
                    <div class="skill-level">mid-level</div>
                    <div class="examples">Data capturers,</br>Social Media coordinator,</br> Desk operator ...etc</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- tech box -->
            <div class="box" id="techBox">
                <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-tie fa-4x"></i></div>
                <div class="content-box">
                    <div class="sub-heading"><h6>Tech & Specialising</h6></div>
                    <div class="skill-level">high-level</div>
                    <div class="examples">App/Web developers,</br> Accountant,</br>Market Analyst...etc</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- student box -->
            <div class="box" id="studentBox">

                <div class="icon"><i class="fas fa-user-graduate fa-4x"></i></div>
                <div class="content-box">
                    <div class="sub-heading-2"><h6>Students</h6></div>
                    <div class="skill-level-2">University/College</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- resource selector -->
        <div class="quote-container" id="quote-body" style="display:none">
        </div>
        <!-- grand total-->
        <div class="" id="gt-div" style="display:none">
            <label id="g-total"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="teamquoteJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess there are a lot of different approaches to solve this. I recently had to do something pretty much like this. The way I did it is add additional class on the top-level div, something like '.clickable' or something and when you handle the click event you check `var element; if ($(this).hasClass('clickable') {element = $(this);} else {element = $(this).closest('clickable');}`

Comment: @Leron, thanks, I'll try that out. I was not aware that you could have multiple classes on one html element. That's really what I needed.

Comment: No problem. I see you are trying to use vanilla JS which seems pretty neat to me, so once you get the element with jQuery you can say `var el = element.get(0);` and you can proceed using `el` as a pure JS element. That's what I've done in my app. Happy coding! :)

Comment: jQuery: $('body').on('click', '.box', function (e) {
          //code here
});